# EF Core: how to load a single item from collection-nav property?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have one-to-many relationship between two entities: **User** (one) has **Messages** (many) collection.

There needs to display some information about User and at the same time needs to load single Message.
I try to do something like:

```
mycontext.Users.Where(..).Include(user => user.Messages.Take(1).First());
```

However this code throws ecxeption

> InvalidOperationException: The property expression 'user=> {from
>       Message m in [chat].Messages select
>       [m] => Take(1) => First()}' is not valid. The expression should
>       represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. For more information
>       on including related data, see
>       http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that the way you have tried.You have to retrieve all the related messages from the db and after that filter it on the memory (`IEnumerable`) as shown below.

```
var useList= mycontext.Users.Where(..).Include(user => user.Messages);

 foreach (var u in useList)
  {

      var message= u.Messages.Take(1).First();

  }
```

Comment: good, but I would change it a little:
<br /> 
` foreach(var u in useList)
{
Message msg = await _context.Messages.Where(ms => ms.UserID == u.ID).Take(1).FirstAsync();
u.Messages.Add(msg);
}`
This approach makes to use async code.

Comment: Wrong: just do the opposite. Load the message **and it's related User**

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy. Instead of trying to load a message from a user, load the user from the message:

```
mycontext.Messages.Where(..).Include(msg => msg.User);
```

In fact, you can do it easier for you:

```
mycontext.Messages
.Include(msg => msg.User)
.Where(msg => msg.User...);
```

So you don't have to filter on Message rather than on User

Comment: Yes, but in my real scenario app sends to client list of **chats** with information about each of them and their **last** message only.

Comment: @Mergasov not sure how that would change anything

Comment: I'm trying do something like this: `context.Messages
.Where(msg => msg.Chat.Users.Any(u => u.Id == currentuser.Id).Include(msg => msg.Chat)`
However, how can I get the last message of each chat **only**? It returns a lot of msg of any chat which related with current user.
I needs GroupBy() method, but it works on client side yet in EF Core.

Comment: @Mergasov I'd guess the messages have an ID, if I'm correct, use OrderByDescending(msg => msg.MessageId)